# Share a page draft in AEM with external user

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

Is there a way in AEM to share unpublished pages (basically drafts) with people who don't have access to the AEM? The only thing I can do right now is to use Snagit to take a full page screenshot, but sometimes the pages have dynamic content that makes the screenshot completely unusable.

Comment: AEMaaCS offers preview service (extra publisher). Using the preview service you can preview a website’s final experience before it reaches the actual publish environment and is available publicly.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-service/content/implementing/using-cloud-manager/manage-environments.html?lang=en#access-preview-service

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-service/content/sites/authoring/fundamentals/previewing-content.html?lang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author server is always authenticated, if this is a on-premise environment, you can deploy a new publish server and use a custom replication to publish the page to this publish server (which ideally should have at least a basic HTTP authentication in front to avoid leaking pages to the wild). If approved, then, you can publish to the other publish servers that are configured to serve the final content.

Probably, the easiest way is to provide limited access to AEM Author server (no edit permissions).

Answer (score 1):

I did this a while ago by creating an aem user in the author instance that has only read permissions to a limited area of the site. Then the external user can log in using those specific permissions.

If wished, you can even create a link to the author instance with a parameter that specifies the system to log the user in automatically to that user, by applying a servlet that implements/extends the DefaultAuthenticationFeedbackHandler.